# Campo do tipo time ou decimal, como resolver?

Tags: javascript, html, banco-de-dados, modelagem, tipagem

Tenho no sistema que estou desenvolvendo um campo chamado vazão, que pode ser preenchido tanto com um valor decimal tipo 0.5 e 2.4 quanto com um valor de tempo, tipo 15 min e 5 h.

Qual a melhor solução no momento de criar esse campo na minha tabela? Deixar como *string* mesmo? Meu receio é que futuramente tenham que usar esses valores para algum calculo e ai pode dar problema.

E no meu `input` para cadastro dessa informação, como posso mascarar isso pra evitar que o usuário digite o que não deve?

Estou pensando em criar 2 campos na tabela, um para cada tipo... E no cadastro da informação colocar um radio ou algo do tipo pra o usuário escolher se vai cadastrar tempo ou valor decimal, e aí eu aplico a máscara. Isso seria ruim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que está pensando na solução certa. Vou elencar as opções.

1. Imaginando que precisaria de cálculos, a melhor solução é não fazer isto. O correto seria uma forma de normalizar o valor. Por exemplo, se optar pela notação decimal, então grave 0,25 para 15min ou 5 para 5h.
2. Se não for possível normalizar adequadamente e realmente precisar saber quando entrou decimal ou em tempo, aí a solução é ter dois campos distintos e um auxiliar indicando qual dos dois usar. Eventualmente não precisaria deste campo auxiliar se puder trabalhar com nulo, assim o que não for usado ficaria nulo. Evidentemente que a aplicação (ou uma restrição no banco de dados) teria que cuidar para nunca ter ambos usados.

Se isto não puder ser feito, qualquer solução será ruim.

3. Entretanto, se o campo é meramente descritivo e pouco importa para a aplicação o que tem dentro dele, aí usar uma *string* pode ser o mais adequado.

O botão para selecionar pode ser uma boa. Dependendo da opção impediria o preenchimento do outro ou até mesmo mudaria o campo único mostrado para o usuário. Pode trocar a máscara. Pode ser que nem precise disto.

É possível a aplicação cliente identificar que um foi digitado e impedir a digitação do outro. Tem que informar bem o usuário que para liberar o outro, se ele quiser, tem que apagar um destes campos. Não estou dizendo que é a melhor solução para seus usuários.

Não posso dizer sobre a máscara porque não sei o que pode e o que não pode. De qualquer forma acho que isso já é uma outra pergunta com um problema diferente (faça separado).

Comment: ótimas opções @bigown, vou ver junto ao cliente mais a fundo sobre a função desse campo para que possa escolher melhor, mas acho que o tipo string vai suprir bem juntamente com um show/hide do campo que o usuário escolher.

Comment: No caso de precisar fazer cálculos, eu poderia normalizar para decimal e ter um campo auxiliar para dizer como o valor deve se comportar, certo?

Comment: Se normalizar não precisaria, porque aí o tempo passa ser gravado como se fosse um valor decimal. Não faz diferença se o usuário entrou em horas ou com decimais, ele guarda decimais e ponto. Como você vai apresentar é problema da aplicação em cada momento, pode apresentar tanto em decimal como em tempo (tem que fazer a conversão, obviamente)

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente a melhor opção é a que você descreveu: dois campos distintos na tabela e o usuário seleciona o que vai inputar pelo radio.

Até porque futuramente fica fácil se você precisar fazer cálculo com os valores e/ou filtrar tudo que foi inputado decimal ou tudo que é horário.